# What are common alternatives to maintaining state in a desktop application other than state machines?

Tags: oop, state-machine

I am working on a desktop application that is a few years old. The application's state (regarding what the user is currently performing (multi-step actions), what computation is being performed, the state of/permissions on the data, background jobs, etc) is maintained through many different methods (event subscription, member variables in controller classes, dependance on the internal logic/behaviour of other classes, etc...)

So my question is, what common patterns (other than explicit state machines) exist to manage the state of the application that are flexible enough to allow:

- state nesting/localization to specific modules (every component's state isn't necessarily needed by every other component. A wizard, for example, would have a private/nested/local state that is exposed to any part of it but not to the entire application)
- state easily exposed/shared/reachable (i.e: the selection in some view needs to be reachable/visible to a copy button and the button would also need to be aware of the context (is the user performing a multi-step operation or is some task running in the background so I can only copy and not cut))

It's a GUI application so we can depend on the hierarchical nature of the application when sharing/reaching different states.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by state? What does it meana to expose/share/reach states? What about localization to spec. modules? The last sentence is totally unclear. Can you please try to rephrase your problem?

Comment: Is it clear enough now ?

Answer (score 0):

State machines are simple enough to be understood by novice programmer, so it may be easier to find a person capable of helping with development later. Also there are few existing libraries and tools to work with state machines, so it may be easier from other aspects. You can also use more than one state machine and let them communicate via some simple pub/sub infrastructure.

Similar approach is [Petri Nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net). It is a bit more complicated, I have no real experience with implementation yet, but it allows multiple states to be active at once to express parallel processes. Otherwise it looks very similar to traditional finite state machine.